# Custom serialization inside a custom serializer?

Tags: json, jackson

I want to serialize subobjects in a Jackson serializer.

So I have an object like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = StateSerializer.class)
public class State {

    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonProperty(value = "d", required = false)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonSerialize(using = StateDefinitionSerializer.class)
    private StateDefinition definition;

    ...
}
```

and inside my StateSerializer I want to serialize my StateDefinition using its own seriliazer named StateDefinitionSerializer:

```
public class StateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<State> {

@Override
public void serialize(State state, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
...
jsonGenerator.writeObject(state.getDefinition());
```

But then I end up getting an IOException inside the jackson DefaultSerializerProvider:

```
} catch (IOException ioe) { // As per [JACKSON-99], pass IOException and subtypes as-is
        throw ioe;
}
```

Any idea's on how to solve this? :)

All help/comments appreciated a lot.

Best wishes,

Jochen

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the annotation of @JsonSerialize(using = StateSerializer.class) NOT above the class, BUT above the object or parameter you want to serialize.

In your case, you can do:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = StateSerializer.class)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
...
private StateDefinition definition;
```